# Master Detail ,MVC Model layer code, for better professional way

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, crud

I am trying to write master detail entry edit in Asp.net MVC model.
Fristly, let me show you two of my model classes.

### Class name  = Model\OrderDetailRepository.cs

```
public class OrderDetailRepository : IOrderDetailRepository
{
    NorthwindEntities DB = new NorthwindEntities();

    public IQueryable<Order_Detail> GetOrderDetailByOrderID(int OrderID)
    {
        return DB.Order_Details.Where(tableX => tableX.OrderID == OrderID);
    }

    public void InsertOrderDetail(Order_Detail _Order_Detail)
    {
        DB.Order_Details.AddObject(_Order_Detail);
    }


    public void UpdateOrderDetail(Order_Detail _Order_Detail)
    {
        DB.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(_Order_Detail, EntityState.Modified);
    }

    public void DeleteOrderDetailByOrderID(int OrderID)
    {
        Order_Detail  _Order_Detail = DB.Order_Details.SingleOrDefault(x => x.OrderID == OrderID);

        if (_Order_Detail != null)
            DB.Order_Details.DeleteObject(_Order_Detail);
    }

    public void DeleteOrderDetailByCurrentRecord(Order_Detail _Order_Detail)
    {
        DB.Order_Details.DeleteObject(_Order_Detail);
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        DB.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

### Class name  = Model\OrderMasterReposity.cs

```
public class OrderMasterReposity : IOrderMasterRepository
{
    NorthwindEntities DB = new NorthwindEntities();

    public IQueryable<Order> GetOrderMasterByOrderID(int OrderID)
    {
        return DB.Orders.Where(tableX => tableX.OrderID == OrderID);   
    }

    public void InsertOrderMaster(Order _Order)
    {
        DB.Orders.AddObject(_Order);
    }

    public void UpdateOrderMaster(Order _Order)
    { 
        DB.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(_Order,  EntityState.Modified);
    }

    public void DeleteOrderMaster(int OrderID)
    { 
        Order _Order = DB.Orders.SingleOrDefault(x => x.OrderID == OrderID);

        if (_Order != null)
            DB.Orders.DeleteObject(_Order);            
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        DB.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

After all upper code, I need to invoke these two class from my controller class.
So let's assume that below code i will write at controller layer.

```
OrderMasterReposity _OrderMasterReposity = new OrderMasterReposity();
OrderDetailRepository _OrderDetailRepository = new OrderDetailRepository();
_OrderMasterReposity.InsertOrderMaster(new Order{....});
_OrderDetailRepository.InsertOrderDetail(new Order_Detail{....});
_OrderMasterReposity.Commit();
_OrderDetailRepository.Commit();
```

What my problem is the way I doing now is not so professional way. 

Because I need to invoke Commit function more than one time.
So, please could anyone give me more nicer way to code at Model layer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Unit of Work, see this example:

http://iridescence.no/post/ASPNET-MVC-DataContext-and-The-Unit-of-Work-Pattern.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Best thing is that u implement Repository pattern properly
Moreover, Order detail has no meaning without order so according to DDD you should not define separate repository for order_detail. i would do it something like

```
Order _order = OrderMasterRepository.GetOrder(orderID);
_order.Property1 = value1;
_order.Property2 = value2;
_order.Property3 = value3;
foreach(var orderDetail in _order.OrderDetails)
{
   orderDetail.Property1 = avalue1;
   orderDetail.Property2 = avalue2;
   .
   .
} 
OrderMasterRepository.Commit();
```

above statements will save data both in order and orderDetail table.